# Java sinhala locale date format using ICU4j not working

Tags: java, locale, icu

I'm working on a project which is Java SE Sinhalese Unicode application and i want to show date in Sinhalese.After searching on stackoverflow i found that i can use ICU4J but it didn't worked.

This the code i have used

```
ULocale locale = ULocale.forLanguageTag("si-LK"); 
dfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM d, YYYY", locale.toLocale());
date = new Date();
lblDate.setText(dfDate.format(date));
```

but it still gives the output in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

worked for me. `ජ 7, 2014`. Make sure you are using ICU's `SimpleDateFormat` in your import.

Answer (score 0):

```
Locale locale = new Locale("si", "LK");
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT, locale);
String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
System.out.print(date);
```